# A Design Of java.util.HashMap field threshold?

Tags: oop, collections, hashmap

HashMap source code define threshold as a default field. why not design it to private field?

```
// (The javadoc description is true upon serialization.
// Additionally, if the table array has not been allocated, this
// field holds the initial array capacity, or zero signifying
// DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.)
int threshold;
```

Comment: Why do you ask specifically about this field?

Comment: Because a package-private member can be acessed in a package. but "threshold" field is only used in HashMap, why it can not be private ? This is about encapsulation.

Comment: So you’re saying all other members of `HashMap` that are not `private` are definitely used outside the class? I mean, except for those members dedicated to serialization (which require the `private` modifier), nothing in this class has been declared `private`. Which suggests that the author had not considered using `private`, *in general*. So considering the general absence of `private` in this class, I have to ask again, why do you ask specifically about this field?

Comment: You are right.  I'm just giving an example of a specifically  field. no special meaning. other filed is also not private. I am confuse why not define field prvite in this class. for serialization ?

Comment: Apparently, the author didn’t care. Some of these members are accessed by the `LinkedHashMap`, so it seems, the author didn’t want to go through all of them and look, which are used and which are not. Further, prior to to JDK 11, accessing `private` members from inner classes made the class file larger, due to the insertion of synthetic helper methods. Perhaps, this was a concern.